# Meteor helper function is always called before Meteor.startup() and called twice instead of once

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

A client side helper function is being called twice in my very simple meteor project.

Three files in the project are:

**websites.js:** MongoDB collection as Model class

**image_share.html**: contains Blaze Template

**image_share.js**: contains helper function for blaze template

Helper function `webSites` is getting called twice which was supposed to be called once. 
Although I'm populating the `mongoDB` collection `Websites` at `Meteor.startup()`, the collection is showing 0 items in the first call and 5 in the second call.

So the question is, why is the helper function being called before Meteor.startup(), why is it being called twice and returning different values in different calls?

Here are the full code:

websites.js:

```
export const Websites = new Mongo.Collection("websites");

Meteor.startup(function(){
  if(Meteor.isServer){
    Websites.remove({});
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      Websites.insert({
        "x": "this is a sample text"
      });
  }
});
```

image_share.html:

```
<head> <title>courseraNewsAgg</title></head>
<body>
    {{> websiteList}}
</body>

<template name="websiteList">
  <h2 >Items: </h2>
    {{#each webSites}}
        <div>
           {{x}}
         </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

image_share.js:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import {Websites} from "/import/websites.js";

Template.websiteList.helpers({
  webSites: function(){
    console.log("list size = " + Websites.find().count());
    return Websites.find();
  }
});
```

Here is the full project with directory structure:
[image]

Here is the output in browser with console log:
[image]

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @RamilMuratov the question is why is the helper function being called before Meteor.startup()  and why is it being called twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is your logging line that caused the helper to re-run.

Note: I don't want to get into the very fine details here since this is a beginner-level question, but I will still try to be precise.

### TL;DR

It ran twice because you did not have the data when the template was first rendered. It has nothing to do with `Meteor.startup()` on the server.

---

Template helpers in Meteor are *[reactive computations](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/)*. Those computations are tracking *reactive data sources*, such as DB query cursors (e.g, the one returned by `Websites.find().count()`.

When something in the computation changes (invalidated), the computation reruns. This is achieved by using Meteor's [*Tracker* mechanism](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/tracker-manual.md) behind the scenes.

### What happens in your case

At page load, your local client's collections are empty. The client subscribes to them (or, if you are using the `autopublish` package, subscriptions are created automatically for you - not really a good thing for production apps).

This is when the template is rendered for the first time, so the helper runs with a result of an empty set of records, but since you have a reactive data source there (the `count()` call), it monitors it.

**Your server may have had the data all along, it just was not yet available to your client.**

After some time, the data arrives from the subscription, the collection is updated and notices that the counts being tracked is now different, so the computation is invalidated and the helper is rerun. This time the client already has the data and the result is a set of 5 documents. It still monitors the cursor for changes.

If you add a new record or remove an existing one on the server somehow (e.g, via a Meteor Method call), the publication will be made aware of it and send the new data to the client.

The client's collection will then be updated and invalidate the *count* computation, which will invalidate the computation in the helper and cause the helper to re-run and query the collection again.

## What if I only return the cursor from the helper

In this case, Blaze (the templating library) will monitor the cursor itself (by *observing* it) and will only perform the required changes in a more granular fashion.

Comment: thanks for your nice explanation!  I guess there is a package named miniMongo which is responsible for synchronizing the the client side database with the server. But it's showing list size 0 each time I refresh the page, don't understand what's the proper explanation?

Comment: MiniMongo is a partial implementation of the MongoDB API. The collections are synced by Meteor's pub/sub mechanism. It needs to receive the data every time the page is loaded, there is no persistence out-of-the-box with MiniMongo.

Answer (score 1):

Putting code in `Meteor.startup` on the client doesn't mean it'll run before any other code, it doesn't block.

Helper runs twice because of reactivity. It runs first when you load page, and then it reruns when you add docs in your db.

If you want to be sure that db is not empty, move your fixtures to server side `Meteor.startup`.